# KnockoutJS - if binding performance

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an observable array with 50 items, rendered with a foreach binding.

I'm trying to understand why the template that each item renders is suffering so much from an `if` binding.  Essentially, I'm showing or hiding a large chunk of my template based on a computed observable.  This is hitting me with a 70-100% render time increase (compared to using a `visible` binding instead).

Ryan Niemeyer's [great post on this topic](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html) indicates that binding a computed to an `if` binding will cause all of the content to re-render each time any part of the computed is updated.  But my computed *does not* change value during the time that the observable array is being looped through.

```
this.filtersAvailable = ko.computed(function () { 
   return this.searchInfo.searchType() != 'invites' && this.searchInfo.searchType() != 'requests' 
}, this);
```

And just to make sure that it's not in fact changing, I added this:

```
this.filtersAvailable.subscribe(function(newVal) { alert("fa" + newVal); });
this.searchInfo.searchType.subscribe(function(newVal) { alert("st" + newVal); });
```

That said, this computed *is* defined at a higher level than the individual view models of my observable array, and is *called* repeatedly both at other places in my template, and of course by every other item in my observable array.

Will this repetitive *calling* of the computed observable cause things bound to it with an `if` binding to re-render?

Comment: Maybe you can get a simplified repro in jsFiddle?  Accessing the value of a computed observable again and again is not a problem, as you get the cached value back each time. Sounds like your subscriptions are not showing frequent updates?   With a computed this will even be if the value is the same.  You can try throwing a `​<div data-bind="text: Date()"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` in your `if` section and see if it looks like the dates are updated more frequently than you would expect.

Comment: @RPN - I added a `<span data-bind="text: new Date().getTime()"></span>` and sure enough, the values are all marching upward as I scroll the list of rendered items.  I'd expect them to all be (about) the same if they were being re-rendered constantly, right?  This isn't really a problem since I can use `visible`; I'm just trying to figure out what the problem is so I can hopefully learn something.  So you're saying an if binding inside of a foreach won't *necessarily* be a problem if the underlying observables aren't updated frequently?

Comment: Yes, if everything was getting re-rendered again and again the dates would likely be close to the same.  For a case where the value is truthy, the `if` binding has slightly more overhead as it takes a copy of the child elements and then renders a copy as the template and binds against it.  `visible` will just set the `display` style.  Now, the `if` binding can give you better performance in cases where the initial value might be false and you have a lot of markup/bindings in the hidden section.  `if` wouldn't even render them, while `visible` would still bind, but just hide.

Comment: You could try a named template too, where you have your `if`.  If you are doing an `if` inside of a `foreach`, then KO has to copy the child elements as a template again and again inside of each `foreach` item.  You can do `<div data-bind="template: { name: 'subItemTmpl', 'if': myFlag, data: subData"></div>`.

Comment: @RPN - thank you so much for the good info up there.  If you'd care to copy that into an answer I'd love to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing the value of a computed observable again and again is not a problem, as you get the cached value back each time. Sounds like your subscriptions are not showing frequent updates?

With a computed this will even be if the value is the same. You can try throwing a ​`<div data-bind="text: Date()"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` in your `if` section and see if it looks like the dates are updated more frequently than you would expect.

If everything was getting re-rendered again and again the dates would likely be close to the same. For a case where the value is truthy, the if binding has slightly more overhead as it takes a copy of the child elements and then renders a copy as the template and binds against it. visible will just set the display style. Now, the if binding can give you better performance in cases where the initial value might be false and you have a lot of markup/bindings in the hidden section. if wouldn't even render them, while visible would still bind, but just hide.

You could try a named template too, where you have your if. If you are doing an `if` inside of a `foreach`, then KO has to copy the child elements as a template again and again inside of each foreach item. You can do `<div data-bind="template: { name: 'subItemTmpl', 'if': myFlag, data: subData"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to form a good idea of what the problem is. But it's likely that you'll see an improvement by using the latest release candidate version of Knockout, which includes optimization to the `if` binding to eliminate unnecessarily re-rendering. It's available for download at https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/downloads.